# geopy NoneType object has no attribute 'latitude'

Tags: python, pandas, geopy

I'm learning geopy and am having trouble understanding the kind of argument that it accepts when returning address or longitude/latitude values.

I have a pandas series with address information I'm trying to get the lat/lon of each address. When geopy returned NoneType error, I thought it had to do with apartment/unit numbers in the addresses. I parsed those out, and the geopy code works for something like

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim()
location = geolocator.geocode("5301 Joyce Street Vancouver")

print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
```

but not:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim()
location = geolocator.geocode("1926 4th Avenue West Vancouver")

print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
```

which returns this:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-055d7e63348a> in <module>()
      2 geolocator = Nominatim()
      3 location = geolocator.geocode("1926 4th Avenue West Vancouver")
----> 4 print((location.latitude, location.longitude))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'latitude'
```

why is this the case?

Comment: `location` is `None`, which indicates that the location was not found. Why it wasn't found, I can't say for sure. I'd report it as a bug.

Comment: @eh2699 did you resolve this issues?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, the reason for the error ~ "NoneType object has no attribute 'latitude'" is because the **geolocator() is not returning any location** resulting variable "location" to be None

```
 location = geolocator.geocode("5301 Joyce Street Vancouver") # returns None therefore, 
 location = None
```

Reason: This Happens because the required location might not be present in the geolocator() library.
Solution: we can't solve this because the geolocator is not having the address of **"5301 Joyce Street Vancouver"**.